# Encfs volume randomly unmounts

Tags: security, mount, macos, filesystem

I have an encfs volume that used to be mounted continuously without any issues.

Some months ago, the volume started occasionally become unmounted - even if there were open files on it!

This unmounting stopped after a few weeks, but yesterday again started happening again. I haven't changed the mount command from the time it was working well.

Any ideas what may be causing this and how to resolve?